# When MySQL/MariaDB is starting, if it has to repair innoDB tables, what happens to queries sent it's way before it's up?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm curious. Are they queued, lost, stuck in php connect_timeout till MySQL/MariaDB comes up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this article](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/xtradbinnodb-recovery-modes/), if you are using the default InnoDB recovery mode, any crash recovery that is done is performed in the background once connections are accepted. The [MySQL manual page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-recovery.html#innodb-crash-recovery) explains this in more detail.

I believe in practice this means that if the server accepts connections, transactions will work normally.